# When does a variable goes out with the revised Simplex method?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

Let be the following linear program.

\begin{cases}
\max & 3x_1& +x_2\\
&x_1&-x_2 &\le -1\\
&-x_1 &-x_2&\le -3\\
&2x_1 &+x_2 &\le4\\
x_1,x_2\ge 0 
\end{cases}

In the normal form it is:

\begin{cases}
\max & 3x_1& +x_2\\
&x_1&-x_2 &+ x_3 &&&= -1\\
&-x_1 &-x_2&&+x_4&&= -3\\
&2x_1 &+x_2 &&&+x_5&=4\\
x_1,x_2\ge 0 
\end{cases}

Which can be written as a dictionary:

\begin{cases}
x_B&=\tilde b&+&\tilde Ax_\bar B\\
c^Tx&=\psi&+&\tilde c ^T_\bar Bx_\bar B
\end{cases}

That is to say:

\begin{cases}
x_B&=A_B^{-1}b&-&A_B^{-1}A_\bar Bx_{\bar B}\\
c^Tx&=c^T_BA_B^{-1}b&+&c^T_BA_B^{-1}A_{\bar B}
\end{cases}

With:

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 &0 &0\\
-1 & -1 &  0 &1&0\\
2 & 1 &  0 & 0 &1
\end{bmatrix}\\ \mbox{if B=1,2,5, }
A_ B=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & -1 & 0\\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{equation}

We also need its invert, **is there any other way than doing the heavy Gaussian elimination?**

$$A_B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & -1/2 & 0\\
-1/2 & -1/2 & 0\\
-1/2 & 3/2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now let's begin to do the dictionary:

\begin{equation}
x_B=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\0
\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & -1/2 & 0\\
-1/2 & -1/2 & 0\\
-1/2 & 3/2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_3\\x_4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_B=
\begin{cases}
1 -1/2(x_3+x_4)\\
2+1/2(x_3+x_4)\\
0-1/2(x_3-x_4)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

**Here is my main question which is revealed to be very important in order to follow and solve this problem: how to know which variable is assigned to each line?**

It should be:

\begin{cases}
(x_1):1 -1/2(x_3+x_4)\\
(x_2):2+1/2(x_3+x_4)\\
(x_5):0-1/2(x_3-x_4)
\end{cases}

**but why?**

Knowing that it is $x_4$,  that enter the basis (because it has an associated reduce cost positive with the basis $B=\{1,2,5\}$ let's solve this program using the revised simplex method:

> In order to know which variable goes out of the basis,
>
> $$A_Bd=A_p$$
>
> find the greatest $t$ such that $x_B-td\ge 0$ (the pivot line p). The value of the incoming variable is $t$. The other variables value is $x_B-td$.

Only studying the effect of $x_4$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$$\begin{cases}
&d_1&-d_2&&=0\\
&-d_1&-d_2&&=1\\
&2d_1 &+d_2 &+ d_3&=0
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
d_1&=-1/2\\
d_2&=-1/2\\
d_3&=3/2
\end{cases}$$

We are going to find the greatest $t$ such that $x_B-td\ge 0$

\begin{cases}
1-t(-1/2)&\ge 0\\
2-t(-1/2)&\ge 0\\
0-t(3/2)&\ge 0
\end{cases}

**It seems that, according to the marking, it is the last line, related to $x_5$, why is it related to such a variable?**